# How can I make a div horizontally slide in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hover, effects

I currently have a div appearing on hover, but it just pops up rather than sliding in:

```
#home-heroImage{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width:980px;
  height: 525px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fcba2e;
}

#home-hero-pop{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity:0.8;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  font: 16px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6d6e70;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 505px;
  width: 460px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Adk8r/4/).

After looking through the posts on SO, I found this example, which would work if I could get it to slide in from the right instead of the bottom. I don't know much about JavaScript or jQuery so the modifications I've tried to make to this code are not producing the desired effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.up-down').mouseover(function(){
        $('.default').stop().animate({
            height: 0    
        }, 200);                        
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('.default').stop().animate({
            height: 200 
        }, 200)    
    })

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPneT/1/).

I've tried reading several JavaScript articles online but they're over my head right now.

Comment: I also created this, but am not sure why it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/v5E3M/

Comment: Invalid markup and all the JavaScript in element attributes? [I'll pass](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kfmkl.gif)

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/TaXj9/ (right to left in stead of down to up)

Comment: Thank you kei, I appreciate it. @Matt, I got the idea to put JavaScript in the elements in this forum, I thought it was a strange approach too, but it worked so I went with it. Any feedback on my markup would be appreciated, helps the learning process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the example you give, here's it sliding in from the right.. is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/jPneT/208/

**EDIT 2017**

> Too much jQuery

You're right, here's a CSS alternative

```css
.left-right {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#333;
}
.slider {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-200px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    transition:0.4s ease;
}

.left-right:hover .slider {
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-right">
  <div class="slider">Welcome !</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is, thank you for your kind reply and providing a solution.

Comment: @Greg No such thing as too much jquery ;) ;)

Comment: Is there a CSS solution where no trigger is needed in order to start the animation? What I mean is, is it possible to just start the animation once the page has loaded?

Answer (score 5):

My answer uses **no JavaScript**. CSS can handle this automatically for you.

Here's a link to a fork of your code as a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/Adk8r/11/

There is only a little change from your example. Rather than hiding the element and showing it with `display` property, the element is placed off-screen using `right: -480px` (where 480 is the cumulative width), and moving it to `right: 0` when the mouse hovers.

Using CSS transitions provides the animation, and support is very good now: http://www.caniuse.com/#search=transition

This technique allows **all browsers back to IE6** view and use your website, but users with older browsers will not have an enhanced experience. Unless you **require** the animation - as in, it is a feature for it to animate - I would suggest using CSS transitions to futureproof your website and use web standards.

*Users of deprecated browsers deserve a deprecated experience.*

Comment: How would you say that support is very good? IE8's share is tremendous and it doesn't support CSS3 animations. He could try CSS3 animations but I would surely advise a JS (preferably jQuery) fallback. Also posting comments on others' solutions (which are more cross-browser friendly) is rather dull.

Comment: This technique allows **all browsers back to IE6** view and use your website, but users with older browsers will not have an enhanced experience.

Comment: Yes, users with pre-IE9 browsers will see a toggled div. The TS' question, though, was to get **rid of this simple toggle** and replacing it with a slide. You can indeed do this with CSS3 but only for modern browsers and not for IE8. Users will experience a toggle without transitions, which is what the TS does **not want**. Why then propose something he does not want. And I disagree with your last sentence. XP users are stuck with IE 8 which does not support what you proposed.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/Adk8r/10/

As said: please learn to write logical and correct HTML. Your markup is **invalid** and **unlogical**. You should perfect your HTML and CSS and *then* study JavaScript and jQuery rather than trying to get a hang of everything at once. This code is a pain to the eye.

Here's what's wrong:

- Try to avoid large chunks of inline style and JavaScript.
- You use a span where one would use a heading-tag (`<h1>Welcome</h1>`) and style it via CSS.
- You use line breaks `<br />` where one would use paragraphs:

  `<p>This div appears on hover but I would like to slide in from the right instead of just appearing.</p>`
- There's no structure in your code. This is not necessary to create a working website, but it's good practice to give child elements an indent of two or four spaces. This way, it's very clear for yourself which element is which child or parent. The same is true for your CSS rules: it's better to put your selector first and then the rules (indented) like so:

  ```
  h1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 160%;
  }
  ```
- You have a closing `</a>` tag but there's no opening `<a>`.

Comment: What is wrong with the markup in my first fiddle? I appreciate any feedback so I can learn to do this properly. I only put partial code in my fiddle so you wouldn't have to bother with the whole page, maybe that's what is wrong?

Comment: thank you for the clarification. Some of the problems are due to copying and pasting chunks of a page into jsfiddle but the H1, br and inline styles are indeed things I need to adopt as best practices. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note: to obtain block code formatting inside a list item, you need to indent it twice. I don't know why, but I think that's standard Markdown syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do it using css3. 
instead of going through the hassle of javascript
try something like in the CSS:

```
div.move {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background:#0000FF;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  padding:10px;
}

/*on mouse hover*/
div.move:hover {
  /*General*/
  transform:translate(200px,100px);
  /*Firefox*/
  -moz-transform:translate(200px,200px);
  /*Microsoft Internet Explorer*/
  -ms-transform:translate(200px,100px);
  /*Chrome, Safari*/
  -webkit-transform:translate(200px,100px);
  /*Opera*/
  -o-transform:translate(200px,100px);
}
```

in the HTML:

```
<div class="move">Anything is here moves!</div>
```

Also the translate works on an x/y axis.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. All you need is HTML, CSS and jQuery.

1. Make a solid div.
2. Make the parent div to hide overflow (`overflow:hidden`) in CSS.
3. Assign a `margin-left` of 100% (or some length) that the required div hides away because of margin.
4. Do a jquery `animate()` function to bring down `margin-left` to 0 or 0%.
5. You can also set the speed of animation by giving time in ms (milliseconds) or some expression like `slow` or `fast`